# Is it efficient to use multiple left join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT b.*, a.deal_id, 
       CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS buyer_name, 
       CONCAT(d.first_name, ' ', d.last_name) AS seller_name, 
       a.payment_method, a.added_delivery, a.item_to_buy_type, a.item_to_buy_description 
FROM prepay_main_staging.pp_dispute b LEFT JOIN 
     pp_deal a 
     ON a.id = b.id_deal LEFT JOIN 
     pp_user c 
     ON c.id = b.id_buyer LEFT JOIN 
     pp_user d 
     ON d.id = b.id_seller 
WHERE b.id_seller = '9' OR b.id_buyer = '9';
```

Is this efficient enough?
i tried this just to get 2 rows from db and the duration taken was 0.344sec. (mysql workbench)

Comment: I t has nothing to do with efficiancy, you make a Left join if you need all the data from the left table joined to the right, as this increases the result set, it is less efficiant  to an inner join.

Comment: Is there any problem with using that query? Have you checked through `EXPLAIN`  whether any indices are missing?

Answer (score 0):

if you really need  LEFT JOIN  you have not other choice .. 
anyway be sure you have proper index on the join involved  column
in your case

```
 table pp_dispute composite index on  (id_deal,id_buyer, id_seller )
```

but your join clause always match then use INNER JOIN  .. for working on a more small result set

Comment: thx.
Definitely will look into index.
looks like it also contribute to the efficiency of the query.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your query is not the `LEFT JOIN`. It is the `WHERE` comparison.  There are two issues;

1. The `OR`.
2. The ids are presumably numbers, not strings.  Don't mix types.

Start with this "half" query:

```
SELECT dis.*, d.deal_id,
       CONCAT(ub.first_name, ' ', ub.last_name) AS buyer_name,
       CONCAT(us.first_name, ' ', us.last_name) AS seller_name,
       d.payment_method, d.added_delivery, d.item_to_buy_type, 
       d.item_to_buy_description 
FROM prepay_main_staging.pp_dispute dis JOIN
     pp_deal d
     ON d.id = dis.id_deal JOIN
     pp_user ub
     ON ub.id = dis.id_buyer JOIN
     pp_user us
     ON us.id = dis.id_seller 
WHERE dis.id_seller = 9;
```

First note that I changed the table aliases to something meaningful -- table abbreviations.  Now the query is much, much easier to follow.

I also changed the `JOIN`s to inner joins and fixed the comparison.

For this query, you want indexes one:

- `pp_dispute(id_seller, id_deal, id_buyer)`

I assume the `id`s in the other table are already declared as primary keys.

See how fast this runs.  If it runs fast, then write the same query for `id_buyer` and use `UNION ALL` to combine them.  MySQL in particular -- and databases in general -- do a poor job of optimizing `OR` conditions.

I should note that you can replace the `JOIN`s with `LEFT JOIN`s and you'll see that doesn't change the performance in this version.  However, the `LEFT JOIN` is probably not logically correct.

Comment: thanks.
it just sometimes when im not using ' $id ' in my php code, the sql return error.
thats why i put ' ' for the variable.

but when i run raw query by using int 9, it indeed improve the query speed.

Comment: @NMAA . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?